# How create sum from tabel 2 and show data tabel 1 and tabel 2

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench

Tabel A :

| id | invoice |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 |
| 2 | 002 |

Tabel B :

| id | invoiceId | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 15 |

Expect

| id | invoice | total | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 10 | 40 |
| 2 | 001 | 20 | 40 |
| 3 | 001 | 10 | 40 |
| 4 | 002 | 15 | 15 |

my relation one to many.
because i need one column with name count base on tabel B sum(price) with group by invoiceId
How to make it mysql query above expect from tabel A and B ?.

Comment: how exactly are count values calculated?

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Also I could see you are not taking any columns from `tableA`. Do you expect `invoice` also in the output?

Comment: What's the point of the invoice column in table1 when it's never used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can handle this without a subquery by using analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT
    b.id,
    a.invoice,
    b.price AS total,
    SUM(b.price) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id) AS count
FROM TableB b
LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON a.id = b.aid;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, or if you are doing this from an ORM layer which doesn't like analytic functions, we can also try using a join to aggregate the counts:

```sql
SELECT
    b1.id,
    a.invoice,
    b1.price AS total,
    COALESCE(b2.count, 0) AS count
FROM TableB b1
LEFT JOIN TableA a
    ON a.id = b1.aid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT aid, SUM(price) AS count
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY aid
) b2
    ON b2.aid = b1.aid;
```